# Inno setup: copy file to backup folder only if it doesn't match file to be installed?

Tags: copy, backup, inno-setup

I've written an Inno Setup script that copies a few existing files to a backup folder, appending the date of the current installation to the backed-up filename, like this:

```
Source: "{app}\vDosDisk\WP51\VDOSPCL.PRS"; DestDir: "{app}\51Config\Backup51"; DestName: "VDOSPCL.PRS.{code:GetTodaysName}"; Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist; Components: InstallForWP51
```

(The GetTodaysName code is someone else's code for building a string from the current date and time.)

Here is my question: Is it possible to write some code that will ONLY create a backup file if the file that is currently on disk is different from the file that my installer is going to install (and thus overwrite the existing file)?

As far as I can tell, none of the built-in flags can accomplish this.

Thanks for any help.